# ASP.NET + SqlDataAdapter not returning correct results with query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I try to run this:

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select top 100 * from table_name order by id desc", conn)

and I am getting all the rows back instead of the last 100.

Comment: Remove `TOP 100` from your select statement.

Comment: Not clear the problem, do you want only 100 rows and this query returns all rows or do you want all rows and this query returns only the last 100?

Comment: I want the last 100 rows in the table

Comment: That query should works. Perhaps there is other code that changes the command. Could you add the code that execute the adapter?

Comment: Put a trace/sql profiler on it..see what is getting sent to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the SQL profiler and check what is the actual query that is being executed in the database.

That should give you more idea about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You have TOP 100 in your SELECT statement thats why it only returns 100 rows. remove TOP 100 fromy your select and it will return all the rows.

> SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER
>   BY id DESC", conn)

Comment: The problem is the contrary. Want 100 rows, but all returns.

Comment: I am only guessing, OP's current query returns TOP 100 and he/she is not happy and says something like `" I am all the rows back, not the last 100."` :S so I am guessing he/she wants all the rows back not only the TOP 100 rows.

Comment: Well see its comment in the question above